# change the parameters of url if it contains space within

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

For example I have written a route like

```
get '/post/:name'
```

If name have some value like `my first post`
and I want to change the value of param abc to 'my-first-post'. please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller's action, you can just grab the param `abc` from the `params` hash and [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) the white spaces with `-`:

```
params[:abc].gsub(/\s+/, '-')
```

You can also gsub the `%20` from the url like this:

```
YourURL.gsub!('%20', '')
```

Then use it as per your need.

Comment: if parameter have spaces then it will be replaced with %20 in url which looks annoying to me how to change that .

Comment: You can do this: YourURL.gsub!('%20', '')